# Is there a function such as the derivative of its inverse is the inverse of its derivative?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

A differentiable bijection $f$ from $I$ (real interval different from an empty one and a point) to $J$.

$f'$ is the derivative of $f$ and a bijection from $I'$ to $J'$.

$g$ is the inverse of $f$ from $J$ to $I$.

And $g'$ has to be the derivative of $g$ and the inverse of $f'$ (from $J'$ to $I'$).

Is there a function $f$ that verifies this condition ?

My conjecture is that there is no such a function.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format posts on this site.

Answer (score 4):

I will assume $f$ is twice differentiable (EDIT: and increasing). As $f'$ is a bijection, either $f''>0$ or $f''<0$ everywhere. So either $f$ is convex or concave. This means its inverse $g$ is concave or convex, respectively, and $g''$ has the opposite sign to $f''$. However, as $f'$ and $g'$ are inverse to each other, $g''(t)=\frac1{f''(g'(t))}$ so $f''$ and $g''$ have the same sign everywhere. That is a contradiction.

EDIT: If the function is decreasing, there is no problem with the signs, as pointed out in the comments below.

Comment: And if $f$ isn't twice differentiable, essentially the same argument works just with considering whether $f'$ is increasing or decreasing.

Comment: You can only say that $f’’\ge 0$ or $f’’\le 0$. This complicates (or even invalidates) your proof.

Comment: @TonyK You are right that "$f'$ is a bijection" is not enough to deduce the strict sign. However, if $g'$ is differentiable then we can differentiate $f'(g'(t))=t$ so $f''(g'(t)) g''(t) =1$ for all $t$. Hence $f''$ and $g''$ are never zero (if they exist).  Anyway, the second derivatives are not necessary and you can replace "$f''>0$" with "$f'$ is strictly increasing" and so on to obtain a proof without second derivatives.

Comment: What makes you think that the inverse of a convex function has to be concave? Consider $f(x):={1\over x}$ $(x>0)$.

Comment: That is easy: I am an idiot. It is true only if the function is increasing. If the function is convex/concave and decreasing, the inverse is convex/concave. So all I have shown is that the function must be decreasing (if it exists).

Comment: Combine that with my result about $1/u = f'(f^{-1}(f'(u))$, and since the right hand side must be negative, so must the left, i.e., the domain interval $I$ must consist entirely of negative numbers. That probably doesn't lead to anything interesting, but...

Answer (score 3):

NOT a complete answer, but just some ramblings to clean up the problem a bit.

First, $f'$ is defined on the same interval as $f$, so your $I'$ is just $I$; I'm going to use $K$ to denote $f'(I)$, rather than using $J'$.

You want
$$
g'(f'(u)) = u
$$
for all $u \in I$. But because $g = f^{-1}$, we know (inverse function theorem) that 
$$
g'(b) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(b))}
$$
for any $b \in K$. Applying this to $b = f'(u)$, and substituting, we get
$$
g'(f'(u)) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(f'(u)))}
$$
From the first equation, you'd like this to equal $u$, for all $u \in I$, i.e., you want to find a function $f$ on some interval $I$ with the property that 
$$
\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(f'(u)))} = u,
$$
or
$$
\frac{1}{u} = f'(f^{-1}(f'(u)))
$$

Now in this equation, you're applying $f^{-1}$ to $f'(u)$, so that means that $K \subset J$. So the problem becomes:

Are there intervals $I$ and $J$ and a function $f: I \to J$, with

- $K = f'(I)$ being a subset of $J$, and
- $\frac{1}{x} = f'(f^{-1}(f'(x)))$ for all $x \in I$ ?

---

Personally, I suspect not, but I don't have any sort of proof.